# Read in multiple google sheet workbooks with a for loop in google colaboratory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have multiple google workbooks all named in a structured way, e.g.:

> Math_Student Assessment Sheet Grade 10 2021-2022
>
> Math_Student Assessment Sheet Grade 9 2021-2022

I made a dic for all the workbook names and variables I would like to declare them as:

```
grade_dict = {'Grade K': 'grade_k',
'Grade 1': 'grade_1',
'Grade 2': 'grade_2',
'Grade 3': 'grade_3',
'Grade 4': 'grade_4',
'Grade 5': 'grade_5',
'Grade 6': 'grade_6',
'Grade 7': 'grade_7',
'Grade 8': 'grade_8',
'Grade 9': 'grade_9',
'Grade 10': 'grade_10'}
```

I tried to read them in:

```
for key, val in grade_dict:
  vars()['math_student_assessment_sheet_' + val + '_2021_2022'] = gc.open('Math_Student Assessment Sheet' + key + '2021-2022')
```

But I get this error:

> ```
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-20-ec7184dea63b> in <module>()
> ----> 6 for key, val in grade_dict:
>       7   vars()['math_student_assessment_sheet' + val + '_2021_2022'] = gc.open('Math_Student Assessment Sheet' + key + '2021-2022')
>
> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
> ```

I am confused: what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over `dictionary`. You will need `.items()` at the end for unpacking keys and values from dictionary. like

```
for key, val in grade_dict.items():
```

Comment: oh yes sorry, I put this but it now says 'unable to locate spreadsheet'. I am very certain I have the name right, could it be because I am trying to reference a folder that was shared with me (and I made a shortcut to that folder in my drive?